# Is there a way of doing chained PayPal Payments?

Tags: paypal

Since PayPal Adaptive Payments is deprecated and all the examples of chained payments I found included the use of that PayPal product, I wonder if there is any way of doing chained payments using PayPal for Marketplaces and the Python SDK. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now called the [PayPal Commerce Platform](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/)

As far as I'm aware it's only open to select PayPal partners, and you need guidance from PayPal in order to use it.

There is a form you can fill out to express interest, and eventually you'll get an email it seems: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/

---

I don't think the SDK is something to worry about at this point; worst case scenario you'll be integrating direct REST HTTPS calls.

---

Assuming the Commerce Platform is *not* available to you... an alternative solution you might consider is receiving normal PayPal payments into your account:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

And applying for Payouts to send out separate lump sums later, for the "chained" portion:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/

The account owner should ask PayPal's business support whether this is permitted for their use case.

Comment: The alternative you gave was already discussed, and the option to take money into our account was dismissed. I'm currently looking into the options with the PayPal Commerce Platform. Thanks for the answer.